# Best practice for exposing record IDs to API users

Tags: mysql, best-practices, uuid

I am extending an API to include the ability to retrieve and update a specific record after the record is created by the user.

Currently, these records are created with an auto generated integer key, for example `49300`.

Users need a way to access a specific record but I don't like the idea of exposing this ID to end users, because it will reveal information about my schema, for example I can assume there is also a record of ID `493299`.

I'm considering a GUID alongside the auto generated integer, but I have concerns about performance as the table size is ~5 million records, growing by 1 million/year.

Is there reason for concern adding a table this size, or the subsequent SELECT query on the GUID when retrieving/updating the record?

I'm using AWS RDS MySQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Indexes on Integer are faster than char, so the  querys aren't usually that fast as before.

Comment: INT vs CHAR -- not that much difference.  Huge tables with a unique on UUID has serious performance problems.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows are created with a Surrogate, numeric key that keeps the database nice and tidy but, for each record, is there a Natural key that would be meaningful to the Users?

For example, a User might log into your Application using an email address.

Each User record would have both a Surrogate, numeric, UserId *that the User never sees* plus their email address (and other stuff).  When joining tables *within* the database, you use the internal, Surrogate key.  For *anything* coming from the Outside World, you use the Natural keys that make sense to Them Out There:

```
create table Users 
( id            int            auto_increment not null 
, email_address varchar( 100 ) not null 
, primary key ( id ) 
, key ( email_address )
); 

select * 
from Users ; 
+----+----------------------------+ 
| id | email_address              | 
+----+----------------------------+ 
|  1 | fred.flintstone@rubble.com |
+----+----------------------------+
```

It might be that one field is not enough to do this.  The Natural, Primary Key of a record might be a *handful* of fields - if that what it takes for Users to get to that record, then that's what they have to enter.

As you quite rightly suspect, you should *never* leak those internal identifiers outside of the database.  *Always* take Real World value[s] and map them back into their internal equivalents.  If nothing else, it gives you an degree of input data cleansing en route.

Comment: I don't think I have an option for a good natural key. This table is a record of API usage, containing the user ID and the ID of the record. The remaining columns are details for a given API call.

Comment: Sounds like this would be used for diagnostic purposes?  Would it, perhaps, be queried by date/timestamp?  OK, that might return multiple rows but the User would not need to know what the ID's of the individual rows were (although your application might do).

Comment: The real life scenario is that each event represents an action within a compliance plan that at some point in the future may require an update, to close any compliance gaps. Hence the need to ID the record.